# GridView item positioning issue

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I have a `GridView` which consist of a `DataTemplate` inside `GridView.ItemTemplate`, the `GridView` is filled with 14 fixed number of items, only 10 are visible and you need to scroll horizontally to see the remaining 4. For each `item` inside the `GridView` their is a like button. I reload the page every time as the user clicks the like button to make some page arrangements (like favourite first). After 10 items are liked when i click any of the remaining for item after scrolling the `GridView` the page is reloaded and positioned to the begining of `GridView` i.e., if the user want to like again or to see the last liked item he need to scroll horizontally to the end. My question in a nutshell is

> how can i prevent the `GridView` from being positioned to the
>   beginning when the layout gets updated??

What I have tried is this, I placed the following code under like button click event..

```
if (Like > 9)
  this.StationListBox.ScrollIntoView(StationListBox.Items[13]);
```

But the problem is that, It works only when the like count is exactly 10.